# Extremely long wavelength electromagnetic radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, radio

High frequencies are used to eject electrons, because only electrons can really be affected at such a small wavelength scale. But could an electromagnetic wave have such a ridiculously low frequency (100s of hertz, maybe) that it could physically vibrate things?

Put differently, can I produce a physical vibration on a highly ferromagnetic (or highly electrically polarizable) rod when I shine a very strong radio source at it?

Comment: Microwaves do this to food; well, maybe not a physical vibration.

Comment: ITU defines radio frequency bands down to [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) spanning 3 - 30 Hz. And these low frequencies have been used for things like communicating with submarines.

Comment: It is almost like spinning a magnet around a magnetic object. That could work if your electromagnetic wave is strong enough.

Comment: @LDC3 I suppose heat is sort of a vibration, right?

Comment: @busukxuan Hm. Interesting point. That would have to be spinning awfully fast though :D